# How to Call the output of an Iterative solution into an array at everytime step (Using Python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sequence

Below is a code where I am solving a problem by (1) Solving a system of equation iteratively using the Newton Method. The result of this iteration, a triple (z0,z1,z2) is used in a second step, step (2) to calculate the values of x=(x0,x1,x2).  I am to repeat this process for, say t =(0,1,5). That is, in the Next step Newton Solves for z again, and this new value of z is used to obtain x again. That means at the end of the day,I need a 3*6 array containing the values of x.

The problems: (1) I seem to find it difficult to call the values obtained for z to be used in the function that solves x
(2) In the function StepFunction,I seem to be calling a sequence "Newton" into an array. I think this is a problem. What I actually want to call is the solution obtained by Newton
(3) And sometimes I get this ValueError:could not broadcast input array from shape (3,5) into shape (3)

You help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
import numpy as np
def Newton_system(F, J, z, zz, x, eps):
    """
    Solve nonlinear system F=0 by Newton's method.
    J is the Jacobian of F. Both F and J must be functions of x.
    At input, z holds the start value. The iteration continues
    until ||F|| < eps.
    """
    #call in the value x from previous iteration
    F_value = F(z,zz,x)
    F_norm = np.linalg.norm(F_value, ord=2)  # l2 norm of vector
    iteration_counter = 0
    while abs(F_norm) > eps and iteration_counter < 100:
        delta = np.linalg.solve(J(z), -F_value)
        z = z + delta
        F_value = F(z,zz,x)
        F_norm = np.linalg.norm(F_value, ord=2)
        iteration_counter += 1

    # Here, either a solution is found, or too many iterations
    if abs(F_norm) > eps:
        iteration_counter = -1
    return z, iteration_counter
z.shape
```

```
def F(z,zz,x):
    k,a,b,c,h = 0.1,0.2,0.2,5.7,6.0` code `
    return np.array([ z[0]-x[0]+h/2*(z[1]+z[2]+k*z[0]-k*zz[0]),
                      z[1]-x[1]-h/2*(z[0]+a*z[1]-k*z[1]+k*zz[1]),
                      z[2]-x[2]-h/2*(b+z[2]*(z[0]-c)-k*z[2]+k*zz[2])])
  


def J(z):
    k,a,b,c,h = 0.1,0.2,0.2,5.7,6.0
    return np.array([[1+h*k/2,h/2,h/2],
                     [-h/2,1-(h*a)/2,h*k/2],
                     [-h*z[2]/2,0,1-h/2*(z[0]-c)-k]])



def DelayedRossler(z,zz):     
    a,b,c,k,h = 0.2,0.2,5.7,0.1,6.0
    return np.array([ -z[1] -z[2] -k*z[2] +k*z[0]-k*zz[0] , 
                     z[0] +a*z[1]-k*z[2] +k*z[1]-k*zz[1],
                     b+z[2]*(z[0]-c)-k*z[2] +k*z[0]-k*zz[0] ])

def StepFunction(f, zinit, xinit, tinit,tfinal, dt):   
    global z
    t = np.arange(tinit,tfinal, dt)
    nt = t.size
    nx = xinit.size  #number of state variables
    nz = zinit.size  #number of state variables
    
    x = np.zeros((nx,nt)) #initialization with nx rows and nt columns
    z = np.zeros((nz,nt))  #initialization with nz rows and nt columns
    zz = np.zeros((nz,nt))  #initialization with nzz rows and nt columns

    x[:,0] = xinit    
    z[:,0] = zinit
    zz[:,0] = zinit    
    
    for n in range (nt-1): 
        z[:,n] = z
        zz[:,n+1] = z[:,n]
        x[:,n] =x
        z[:,n+1] = Newton_system(F, J, z , zz, x , eps =0.0001)
        s = dt*f(t[n] +dt/2, z[:,n+1],zz[:,n+1]) 
        x[:,n+1] =  x[:,n] + s
    return x, t 
  

#Define Problem
f= lambda t, z: DelayedRossler(z,zz)

#solve the problem
zinit = np.array([0.0,0.0,0.0])
xinit = np.array([0.0,0.0,0.0])
tinit = 0.0
tfinal = 30.0
dt = 6

x, t = StepFunction(f, zinit, xinit, tinit,tfinal, dt)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to put a two-dimensional array into a one-dimensional array.
Try re-shaping the array that you put the values into a 3x5 array using array.reshape(3,5).